# Golang - How to read many tables on SQL Server PROC Execution

Tags: sql-server, go

I'm using Go to execute a Stored Proc, this Proc answer 2 tables, I've tried to use `rows.NextResultSet()` to try to access to next table, but I can not deal with Procs that respond many tables.
I'm using the [github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb](https://www.github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb) driver.

For privacy reasons I can not post the code, but this is an example:

```
// Connection code above ...

ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 6*time.Second)
defer cancel()

// Emulate the many tables result
row, err := db.QueryContext(ctx, "SELECT 'algo' = '1' ; SELECT 'algo2' = '2', 'algo3' = '3'")
if err != nil {
    return
}

var mssg, mssg2 string
for row.NextResultSet() {

        for row.Next() {

            var cols []string
            cols, err = row.Columns()
            if err != nil {
                return
            }
            log.Println(row.Columns())
            switch len(cols) {
            case 1:

                if err = row.Scan(&mssg); err != nil {

                    return
                }
                log.Println("mssg ", mssg)
            case 2: 
                if err = row.Scan(&mssg, &mssg2); err != nil {

                    return
                }
                log.Println("mssg ", mssg, "mssg2 ", mssg2)
            default:
                continue
            }
        }
}
```

If I comment the `for row.NextResultSet() {}` the `rows.Next()` just iterates over the first `SELECT`.

If I print `log.Println(row.NextResultSet())` it is always false

How can I read each result set?

Answer (score 1):

After reading and trying different ways to solve this I found the solution, I think [the docs](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Rows.NextResultSet) are not clear at all.
The solution was:

1. Iterate over all rows of the first result set (`rows.Next()`)
2. Evaluate `if rows.NextResultSet() {}`
3. If true iterate over all rows of the next result set
4. Do 2 an 3 'till `rows.NextResultSet() == false`